# Correct import of class

Tags: python

Let's say I have 3 scripts: A.py, B.py and C.py

A.py - contains Flask API
B.py and C.py - Performs few functions

1. I have to import a class D from C.py to be used in B.py
2. I am also importing a function from B.py into A.py
3. Eventually, I have to run A.py which is my rest Flask API.

My question is:

A.whether class D (from C.py) should be imported into A.py, from where I can send it to B.py in the form of a parameter to a function (2)

or

B. should I directly import it into B.py

Comment: This seems to depend entirely on what you actually want to *do* with your class and function. Both options work. Can you give some context?

Comment: if you will always use class D then directly import it, if you may want to use something else pass as argument.

Comment: I would probably import it directly into B.py. That way B.py will be able to stand on its own.

Comment: If you ask because of optimization (needing to import into two different modules) then there is absolutely no difference since module C is only loaded once: see the note at the bottom of [this section in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules)